# get partial running status of application using jython

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

Hi I need to know if the application is running partially. using the following command I am able to get info if the application is running.

```
serverstatus = AdminControl.completeObjectName('type=Application,name='+n1+',*')
print serverstatus
```

Is there any other was to check if the current status of application is partially running.??

Regards
Snehan Solomon

Comment: Can you please explain "partially running"?

Comment: @dims I believe "partially running" in the admin console means that the application is running on some but not all cluster members.  I believe you need to compare the list of servers the application is running on against the list of servers you're interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accurately determine whether the application is partially started/stopped, you must first determine the deployment targets against which the application is deployed, and then determine whether or not the application is running on that server:

```
def isApplicationRunning(applicationName, serverName, nodeName) :
    return AdminControl.completeObjectName("type=Application,name=%s,process=%s,node=%s,*" % (applicationName, serverName, nodeName)) != ""

def printApplicationStatus(applicationName) :

    servers = started = 0
    targets = AdminApplication.getAppDeploymentTarget(applicationName)
    for target in targets :
        type = AdminConfig.getObjectType(target)
        if (type == "ClusteredTarget") :
            clusterName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(target, "name")
            members = AdminUtilities.convertToList(AdminConfig.getid("/ServerCluster:%s/ClusterMember:/" % clusterName))
            for member in members :
                serverName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(target, "name")
                nodeName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(member, "nodeName")
                started += isApplicationRunning(applicationName, serverName, nodeName)
                servers += 1
        elif (type == "ServerTarget") :
            serverName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(target, "name")
            nodeName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(target, "nodeName")
            started += isApplicationRunning(applicationName, serverName, nodeName)
            servers += 1

    if (started == 0) :
        print "The application [%s] is NOT RUNNING." % applicationName
    elif (started != servers) :
        print "The application [%s] is PARTIALLY RUNNING." % applicationName
    else :
        print "The application [%s] is RUNNING." % applicationName

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    printApplicationStatus(sys.argv[0]);
```

Note that the [`AdminApplication` script library](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_7libapp1.html#rxml_7libapp1__scr3) only exists for WAS 7+, so if you are running an older version, you will need to obtain the deployment targets yourself.

Comment: Woow, this is indeed a robust method compared to mine. It'll definitely help somebody with a similar requirement. Thanks a ton anyways for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the partial status of application based on the number of nodes. I just hardcoded the number of nodes and then compared them against the number of MBeans they returned.

```
import sys
appName = sys.argv[0]
appCount=0
nodeCount=2
appMBeans = AdminControl.queryNames('type=Application,name='+appName+',*').split("\n")
for mbean in appMBeans:
if mbean != "":
    appCount=appCount+1
print "Count of Applications is %s" %(appCount)
if appCount == 0:
    print "----!!!ALERT!!!!---- The Application "+appName+" is Not Running"
elif appCount > 0 and appCount < nodeCount:
    print "----!!!ALERT!!!!---- The Application "+appName+" is Partially Running"
elif appCount == nodeCount:
    print "The Application "+appName+" is Running"
```

Comment: This approach is _incredibly_ fragile. The number of servers that the application is deployed to does not necessarily correspond to the number of nodes that exist. It may be possible that multiple servers exist on a single node or that the application is not deployed to every node, for example. I've added a much more robust and accurate [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722745/get-partial-running-status-of-application-using-jython/8219248#8219248).